# Performing Get Copy All Operation With Microsoft Sync Framework

Tags: frameworks, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm testing out Microsoft Sync Framework to try and see if it'll be suitable for a task that I'm working on. One of the things I'd like to be able to do is to have the option to not just send changed files, but instead to send all of the files (for example, if I'm syncing to a client machine for the first time, and so want to send all files).
I can't seem to find an example of this in the documentation, so any advice would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're synching for the first time, then there is nothing special to configure as it will sync everything.

if you've already synched and want to re-send all files regardless of whether they've changed or not, just delete the metadata file and that should remove all knowledge of what has been synched.